# Button not respond to on click event

Tags: android, button, onclick, event-handling

I'm trying for hours to make the button click but for some weird reason it doesnt work. 
I have the main activity and from there I set the content view to first run activity and this is the code of the first run activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class FirstRun extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_run);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Test","test");
            System.out.println("Button one is pressed");
            button.setText("Test");
            //Get edit text values
            EditText nameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
            EditText ageET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Age);
            EditText emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
            EditText phoneET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Phone);
            //set data in the info
            //info = new UserInfo(nameET.getText().toString(),emailET.getText().toString(),phoneET.getText().toString());
            if (nameET.getText().toString() != "" && ageET.getText().toString() != "" && emailET.getText().toString() != "" && phoneET.getText().toString() != "") {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("Name", nameET.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Email", emailET.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Phone", phoneET.getText().toString());
                editor.putInt("Age", Integer.parseInt(ageET.getText().toString()));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Xml Layout details about the layout of the app and the button
i tried to add to the button onclick event on xml but every time I did it the app just crush and didn't respond at all

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/welcome_to_my_app"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/please_fill_the_information"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="7">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:capitalize="sentences"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="@string/phone"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Phone"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:text="@string/age"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Age"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="@string/next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does your Log run?

Comment: I tried to change the text of the button too cause I wasn't sure and that doesn't work either